# How can I make the two median lines different colors in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the two median lines different colors in R?

```
df$Values <- as.numeric(df$Values)
df$Month <- factor(df$Month, levels = month.abb)
df$Type <- factor(df$Type, levels = c("Paddy", "No Paddy"))

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = Month, y = Values, fill = Type)) +

  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  
  stat_summary(
    fun.y = median,
    geom = 'line',
    aes(group = Type),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
    size = 5,
    linetype = "dotted",
    colour = 'black'
  ) +
  
  theme_bw() + 
  
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Groundwater (m)") +
  
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 20, color = 'black'),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 20, color = 'black'),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    
    legend.position = c(0.9, 0.08),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 20, color = 'black'),
    legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm'),
    
    panel.border = element_rect(size = 1, color = 'black')
  )
```

[image]
For example, I would like to make the upper dotted line red and the lower dotted line blue.

Comment: Try with `stat_summary(..., aes(group = Type, color = Type), ...)` and dropping the `color="black"`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: @stefan According to you, the median line is not distinguished well because it is the same color as the boxplot. So I want to designate a different color from boxplot.

Comment: After mapping on the `color` aes you can set your desired colors for the lines using e.g. `+ scale_color_manual(values =c ("red", "blue"))`